# Need to Send Data From Ruby to C# via Internet

Tags: c#, ruby

I am working with a client that uses Ruby.  They need to send me strings of data, probably in JSON format.  I am using C# .Net 4.5.  I am wondering what would be a good way to setup a solution where they can send me this information.  We have a private connection setup so there is no need for encryption.  I just need a very simple channel setup to receive their data.

I'm not as familiar with internet communications as I should be, although I think I'm about to become much more intimate.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: when talking about communication programming languages doesn't matter at all, what matters is the protocol and since you're talking about internet then we're talking about HTTP which pretty much every programming language can talk it.

Comment: HTTP is designed to let the client request data from the server, not the other way round - although you can send data together with the request. If it is just the client sending data to the server, HTTP is not appropriate, although it would be possible somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about sockets? They are available in both languages, and you can even communicate between different machines easily (preferrably TCP/IP then?).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html